# I cannot center the text of a userdefined Button

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I created a Button and I set its UIID to boutonPpal. I set the bgAlign attribute to `ALIGN_CENTER` in the resource Editor but the text of the Button is not centered at runtime !

So how to make the text centered ?

Comment: bgAlign sounds like it would align the background of the item, not the text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bgAlign aligns the background image of a component. Use the "Align" tab if using the latest LWUIT. If you are using 1.4 you need to actually invoke setAlign() on the component since in 1.4 alignment was not a part of the theme.